# Populate (tree) view from list generated in model?

Tags: treeview, odoo, openerp-7

What I'm trying to achieve is simple: I made a wizard that asks the user to provide a RMA ID (that's a pop-up). Once that is submitted, I perform some operations in the backend and build a list containing all the other products in the order that's being RMA'd. I then need to ask the user to verify that all those products are in the physical RMA.

Now, I'm stuck right after building my list. How can I send that list to OpenERP, have it generate a TreeView from it so that the user can individually select products that have been located (and the ones that haven't)?

I'm assuming I'll need an additional view.xml, buy I have no idea about:

1) What to insert in the `<field name="arch" type="xml>` node

2) How to send my custom list/object to OpenERP/odoo

In other words, I have a list that I'm trying to send to OpenERP/odoo to be displayed in a TreeView. How?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

@Pier

Considering for Odoo-v8.

From my understanding you can try the following:

In you wizard you need to have a `one2many` field say `product_line_ids`, which will shown in your wizard.

So you will two classes, see the following structure

```
class rma_wizard(models.Model):
_name = 'rma.wizard'

rma_id = fields.Many2one('rma.master',string="RMA")
prodcut_line_ids = fields.One2many('product.line','wizard_id',string="Products")

@api.onchange('rma_id')
def rma_id_change(self):
   code to get the list of products and use the following code to add in the wizard 
   final_products_list = []
   products= {}
   for product in product_list:
    result = {}
    result.update({'product_id':product.id})
    final_product_list.append(result)
   self.product_line_ids= final_product_list

class product_line(models.Model):
_name='product.line'

wizard_id = fields.Many2one('rma.wizard',stirng="RMA")
product_id=fields.Many2one('product.product',string="Products")
select_product=fields.Boolean("Select")`
```

and the **Views**:

```
 <record name="rma_wizard_view" model="ir.ui.view"/>
        <field name="name">RMA Wizard</fieeld>
        <field name="model">rma.wizard</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="rma_id"/>
                <field name="product_line_ids>
                    <tree string="Products">
                        <field name="product_id"/>
                        <field name="select_product"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>        
        </field>
 </record>
```

Now you can put the check mark select as per your need and perform operation on it

Hope this helps!!